# How do i find an exact string within a string using python

Tags: python, string, csv, opencsv

Using a simple "if "blank" in string" statement i would like to find an exact word in a csv column.

```
with open("example.csv","r") as file
reader=csv.reader(file)

string=""

for row in reader:
    if "Hello" in row[0]:
        string+=row[0]

print(string)
```

If the csv has `"Hello World"` in row[0] string will equal "Hello World" but I only want string to `+=row[0]` if specifically only "Hello" is in row[0] without "World".

In conclusion, I'm hoping the code prints nothing unless exactly "Hello" is in row[0].

Comment: `if "Hello" in row[0] and "World" not in row[0]` ? or just `if "Hello" == row[0]` ?

Comment: Or if row[0] == "Hello", depending on how strict they want to be.

Comment: i think you should replace `in` with `==` to check for exact equality

Comment: HA i feel stupid now. i've been up coding for too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if one string is exactly the same as another using `==`:

`if row[0] == "Hello":`

That will find you all the rows with an exact value. You should only use `in` if you are looking for *part* of a string.

If you want to find "Hello" when it is part of a string except when it is followed by "World", then you could try

`if "Hello" in row[0] and not "Hello World" in row[0]:`

For anything more complicated, you'd need to look into [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).